# 2012 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Pro Webmasters' [second moderator election](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the two new moderators are:

[image: paulmorriss] [image: Christofian]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/about#moderators) shortly - please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Answer (score 7):

Congratulations to both of you! Welcome to the team!

Answer (score 1):

Many congratulations to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Good luck to both. I'm sure you'll do a good work.

Comment: It's a shame you didn't win the election but we're still happy and lucky to have you "on our team".

Comment: @JohnConde Thank you for the nice words, I really appreciate. Since I haven't win I'll continue to flag instead of do the work directly waiting for your action :-p

Answer (score 0):

Congrats to you both and all that were nominated